# Keep background image when using Eraser

Tags: javascript, draw, paperjs

I need to build a drawing board with erase function using PaperJS. The drawing board need to have a background image and people can draw on the canvas or erase existing path.

```
//erase function 
function onMouseDown(event) {   
    path = new paper.Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'red';
    path.strokeWidth =  10;
    path.strokeCap = 'round';
    path.blendMode = 'destination-out';
}       

function onMouseDrag(event) {        
    path.add(event.point);                 
}

//setup background image 
var bgimage = "./cat.jpg"; 
var raster = new paper.Raster({
    source: bgimage, 
    position: paper.view.center
});
```

The problem of using this method is that the background image will also be erased.

Erase Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D4TU.png
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kaffsg4/2/

Is there any way to erase the existing path, without erase the background image?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Is the background image going to be editable?

Comment: Should the eraser add some white (that's what your code does), remove the color (it would reveal the background image) or cut/split/remove the existing paths (to work only with vectors)?

Answer (score 0):

If your background image does not change: you can put it in an `<img>` bellow your `<canvas>`?

If you want to be able to edit your image: you can redraw the image, then your drawing (treated separately), every frame.

Comment: I already place the img outside the canvas. This is my working example https://jsfiddle.net/9kaffsg4/2.

Comment: Not if you don't tell me more about your problem.

Comment: I have specified an image as the background of drawing board. I want the background image not affected by the eraser or cleared by canvas.

Comment: How the eraser takes the background color or make transparent lines ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using two canvas (one is for basic drawing function, the other is the background canvas). And then overlap the two canvas.

Comment: Did you consider using layers?

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on your initial code example so that I could demonstrate using layers as a solution. Basically, three layers are created. They are created in the order you see them in (1:background, 2:foreground, 3:clearBtn). The layers created earlier are visualy "underneath" the layers created later.

In this way, you can keep your static raster graphic on the bottom-most layer (background), create your "eraser" paths on the middle layer (foreground), and you can remove/clear these "eraser" paths by clicking on the "clear" button. The clear button is on the top-most layer so that it doesn't become obscured by the "eraser paths". I just added the clear button to emphasize the added organizational control that layers provide.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.9.12/paper.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
  var layers = {
    "background": new Layer(),
    "foreground": new Layer(),
    "clearBtn": new Layer()
  };
  
  var paths = [];
  
  //erase function 
  function onMouseDown(event) { 
      layers.foreground.activate();
      path = new paper.Path();
      path.strokeColor = 'red';
      path.strokeWidth =  10;
      path.strokeCap = 'round';
      path.blendMode = 'destination-out';
      paths.push(path);
  }       
  
  function onMouseDrag(event) {  
      layers.foreground.activate();
      path.add(event.point); 
  }
  
  //setup background image 
  layers.background.activate();
  var bgimage = "http://placehold.it/300x150"; 
  var raster = new paper.Raster({
      source: bgimage, 
      position: paper.view.center
  });  
  
  // Build a "clear button"
  // Clicking this will remove all children
  // from the foreground layer
  layers.clearBtn.activate();
  var clearBtn = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: new Point(250, 2),
    size: new Size(50, 20),
    style: { 
      fillColor: 'white',
      strokeColor: 'black'
    }
  });
  var txt = new PointText({
    point: clearBtn.position + new Point(0,4),
    content: 'Clear',
    justification: 'center'
  });
  var clearBtnGrp = new Group({
    children: [clearBtn, txt]
  });
  clearBtnGrp.on('mousedown', function () {
    for ( var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++ ) {
      paths[i].remove();
    }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit** I updated this to cache paths in an array because the previous example did not always clear all layer children.

Comment: I should add that it is necessary to activate each layer that you wish to draw on.